# use-package rg - install not supported in nil

Tags: package

Given:
Linux Mint 20.3

Emacs 29.1

in my init.el

```
(use-package rg
  :ensure t
  :ensure-system-package rg)
```

I successfully install ripgrep like this

```
apt install ripgrep
```

OK.
But when try to load this package rise error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "install not supported in nil")
  signal(error ("install not supported in nil"))
  error("install not supported in nil")
  (if command nil (error (format "%S not supported in %S" action system-packages-package-manager)))
  (let ((command (cdr (assoc action (cdr (assoc system-packages-package-manager system-packages-supported-package-managers))))) (noconfirm (if system-packages-noconfirm (progn (cdr (assoc 'noconfirm (cdr ...))))))) (if command nil (error (format "%S not supported in %S" action system-packages-package-manager))) (setq command (if (string-match-p "%p" command) (replace-regexp-in-string "%p" pack command t t) (concat command " " pack))) (if noconfirm (progn (setq args (concat args (and pack " ") noconfirm)))) (concat command args))
  system-packages-get-command(install "rg" nil)
  (let ((command (system-packages-get-command action pack args)) (default-directory (if system-packages-use-sudo "/sudo::" default-directory)) (inhibit-read-only t)) (async-shell-command command "*system-packages*"))
  system-packages--run-command(install "rg" nil)
  system-packages-install("rg")
  (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? 'rg) nil (system-packages-install "rg"))
  (if (not (require 'rg nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'rg) :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg nil) (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? 'rg) nil (system-packages-install "rg")) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg t))
  (prog1 (if (not (require 'rg nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'rg) :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg nil) (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? 'rg) nil (system-packages-install "rg")) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg t)) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package rg" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package rg"))))
  (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package rg") (prog1 (if (not (require 'rg nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'rg) :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg nil) (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? 'rg) nil (system-packages-install "rg")) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg t)) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package rg" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package rg")))))
  (progn (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg nil) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package rg") (prog1 (if (not (require 'rg nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'rg) :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg nil) (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? 'rg) nil (system-packages-install "rg")) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg t)) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract ... now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package rg" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package rg"))))) (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg t))
  (condition-case err (progn (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg nil) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package rg") (prog1 (if (not (require 'rg nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'rg) :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg nil) (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? 'rg) nil (system-packages-install "rg")) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg t)) (let ((elapsed (float-time ...))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package rg" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package rg"))))) (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg t)) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning47 :catch err)))
  (progn (use-package-statistics-gather :use-package 'rg nil) (use-package-ensure-elpa 'rg '(t) 'nil) (defvar use-package--warning47 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (progn (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg nil) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package rg") (prog1 (if (not (require ... nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" ...) :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg nil) (if (use-package-ensure-system-package-exists? ...) nil (system-packages-install "rg")) (use-package-statistics-gather :config 'rg t)) (let ((elapsed ...)) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package rg" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package rg"))))) (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg t)) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning47 :catch err))) (use-package-statistics-gather :use-package 'rg t))
  eval((progn (use-package-statistics-gather :use-package 'rg nil) (use-package-ensure-elpa 'rg '(t) 'nil) (defvar use-package--warning47 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg ...)) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (progn (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg nil) (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package rg") (prog1 (if (not ...) (display-warning ... ... :error) (use-package-statistics-gather :config ... nil) (if ... nil ...) (use-package-statistics-gather :config ... t)) (let (...) (if ... ... ...)))) (use-package-statistics-gather :init 'rg t)) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning47 :catch err))) (use-package-statistics-gather :use-package 'rg t)) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```